# Uninstalling Ijavascript and ijs

Tags: node.js

I have installed nodejs from conda using command: `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs` 
After that I used these two commands:

```
sudo npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
```

Now, my javascript kernel is continuously dying and not starting:
[image]

Restarting efforts were futile.

My terminal is showing these outputs:

[image]
[image]

It is suggesting to reinstall and recompile. Reinstalling means uninstalling then installing but what should I uninstall among nodejs, ijavascript and ijs?

I followed this site to install javascript: https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript

They suggested to use these commands:
[image]

But, I have used conda to install nodejs and last two commands were same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First uninstall ijavascript and nodejs:

```
npm uninstall ijavascript

conda uninstall nodejs
```

After that run the following commands:

```
conda install nodejs
npm install -g ijavascript
ijsinstall
```

**Detailed Answer:**

1. As it is written in conda documentation we shouldn't use sudo while installing packages with conda. Once you run conda with sudo, you must use sudo forever.

https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#permission-denied-errors-after-using-sudo-conda-command

2. But in this case we didn't used sudo for installing nodejs we used sudo for ijavascript only?

Again quoting conda:
"On Windows, macOS, and Linux, it is best to install Anaconda for the local user, which does not require administrator permissions and is the most robust type of installation. However, if you need to, you can install Anaconda system wide, which does require administrator permissions."

We shouldn't use sudo (not even for running npm install -g ijavascript).